# Help! SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]

Tags: functions, matrix, programming

I am trying to run this code:

```
> iSmed = List[F3[[r]], F4[[r]], F5[[r]], F6[[r]]];
> \[Beta]med = Table[iSmed[[j]]/\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
1\), \(4\)]\(iSmed[[i]]\)\), {j, 1, 4}];
> \[Lambda]m =  List[(*7F3*)\[Lambda]3[[r]]*10^-9,(*7F4*)\ 
[Lambda]4[[r]]*10^-9,(*7F5*)\[Lambda]5[[r]]*10^-9,(*7F6*)\ 
[Lambda]6[[r]]*10^-9];

> J = 4; \[Epsilon]o = 8.85418*10^-12; h = 6.626*10^-34; e = 1.60218*10^-19; 
>c= 2.9979 10^8 ;  me = 9.10938*10^-31; 

> n[i_] := List[1.9, 1.9, 1.9, 1.9][[i]];

> \[Chi]ED[i_] := (n[i]^2 (n[i]^2 + 2)^2)/9; \[Chi]MD[i_] := n[i]^3;

> U = ( {
   {0.0137, 0.0010, 0.0007},
   {0.0003, 0.0019, 0.0015},
   {0.0139, 0.0010, 0.0026},
   {0.0007, 0.0013, 0.0011}
  } ); 

> Aoe[i_] := (16 \[Pi]^3 e^2)/( 3 \[Epsilon]o h \[Lambda]m[[i]]^3) \ 
[Chi]ED[i]/ (2 J + 1) ; 
> Amd[i_, k1_, k2_] := (\[Pi] h e^2)/( 3 \[Epsilon]o (me^2) (c^2) (\ 
[Lambda]m[[i]]^3) ) \[Chi]MD[i]/ (2 J + 1) LgS[k1, k2][[i]];
> LgS[k1_, k2_] := List[0, 0, k2, k1];

> M11 = Aoe[1] U[[1]][[1]]; M12 = Aoe[1] U[[1]][[2]]; M13 = Aoe[1] U[[1]] 
 [[3]];
> M21 = Aoe[2] U[[2]][[1]]; M22 = Aoe[2] U[[2]][[2]]; M23 = Aoe[2] U[[2]] 
[[3]];
> M31 = Aoe[3] U[[3]][[1]]; M32 = Aoe[3] U[[3]][[2]]; M33 = Aoe[3] U[[3]] 
[[3]];
> M41 = Aoe[4] U[[4]][[1]]; M42 = Aoe[4] U[[4]][[2]]; M43 = Aoe[4] U[[4]] 
[[3]];

(*Matrix elements of b*)
>b1[y_, k1_, k2_] := (\[Beta]med[[1]]/(y*0.001)) - Amd[1, k1, k2];
>b2[y_, k1_, k2_] := (\[Beta]med[[2]]/(y*0.001)) - Amd[2, k1, k2];
>b3[y_, k1_, k2_] := (\[Beta]med[[3]]/(y*0.001)) - Amd[3, k1, k2];
>b4[y_, k1_, k2_] := (\[Beta]med[[4]]/(y*0.001)) - Amd[4, k1, k2];

(*Matrix representation*)
> M = ( {{M11, M12, M13}, {M21, M22, M23}, {M31, M32, M33}, {M41, M42, M43}
  } );
> b[y_, k1_, k2_] := ( { {b1[y, k1, k2]}, {b2[y, k1, k2]}, {b3[y, k1, k2]},
   {b4[y, k1, k2]} } ); 
(*least squares*)
> Op[bb_, y_, k1_, k2_] := Flatten[LeastSquares[M, b[y, k1, k2]]];
```

This code worked with no problem in an early version Mathematica 8.0. However, now the message SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] came up. Please help me to solve this problem, what is going on?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior with version 11.3 for macOS. Are you sure that it is only this code and nothing else that produces the error?

Comment: Yes, I think the code is ok because it compiled and ran with mathematica 8.0. My problem started when I actualized the software

Comment: Hi @Ameli and welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and paste the code in `InputForm` (Use `Sum` and not `SubsuperscriptBox`) and without  the `>` characters?  Here its considered helpful to show your code in a **[well formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)** so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and  see the problem you are facing.